# Checking a set of checkbox if a checkbox is checked in Bootstrap or not.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello, I'm having a problem when performing this in bootstrap 3. I have this code working in jsfiddle but it doesn't work bootstrap.

Here's the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZe5X/135/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 span6 privilege-container-b">
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mypriv" value="test_priv1" class="test_priv1">Checkbox 1</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mypriv" value="test_priv2" class="test_priv2">Checkbox 2</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mypriv" value="test_priv3" class="test_priv3">Checkbox 3</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mypriv" value="test_priv4" class="test_priv4">Checkbox 4</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mypriv" value="test_priv5" class="test_priv5">Checkbox 5</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mypriv" value="test_priv6" class="test_priv6">Checkbox 6</label>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.test_priv1').change(function () {
    var val = $('.test_priv1').is(':checked');
    if (val === true) {
        $('.test_priv2, test_priv3').prop('checked', true);
        $('.test_priv2, test_priv3').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('.test_priv2, test_priv3').prop('checked', false);
        $('.test_priv2, test_priv3').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    return false;
});
```

The code above doesn't work. My goal is if test_priv1 is checked, test_priv2 and test_priv3 will be checked and locked. Any thing wrong with my code? Please correct me guys. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of it *not* working?

Comment: missing `.` before `test_priv3` in `'.test_priv2, .test_priv3'`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gMgm7/1/

Comment: im sorry for the typo, im so annoyed why it won't work in my jsp :( but it works on fiddle

Comment: did you place the code in a dom ready handler? is there any error in your browser console? whether the input elements are created dynamically using another script

Comment: if it works in fiddle but not in your file then definately you have misplaced scripts or events are not attached  to it if they are created dynamically.

Comment: yep i placed it on document ready

Comment: try using $(document).on("click",".test_priv1",function(){
your code
});

Comment: Thanks niko it works, but the clicked checkbox is not checked. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add the dot to the text_priv3 selector and do

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/46B4w/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.test_priv1').on("click", function () { // IE<9 triggers change after blurred
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var $otherChecks = $('.test_priv2, .test_priv3');
        $otherChecks.prop('checked', checked);
        $otherChecks.prop('disabled', checked);
        $otherChecks.parent().toggleClass("disabled",checked);
    });
});
```

Note I also greyed the label text

If you by the way want to grey out all the other boxes, regardless of class you can do

```
var $otherChecks = $("input[name='mypriv']:not('.test_priv1')");
```

or

```
var $otherChecks = $("input[name='mypriv']").not(this);
```